# IOS Swift - Manually trigger textfield events

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How do I trigger the events manually given the UITextField object?

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)
textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)
textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)
textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)
```

In the current scenario. There is some logic which goes into the above callbacks. And there are times when I manually update a textfield

```
textfield.text = <new text>
```

And I would like the

```
textFieldDidBeginEditing
```

to be trigger, like (hopefully)

```
textfield.trigger("textFieldDidBeginEditing")
```

While my approach might not be entirely the right way, the above solution is what would most likely works for me. Although, If I can word my question differently, it would be:

- **How can I run some logic (code) when a UITextFields value (text) is changed via the UI or via** `textfield.text = <new value>`

Comment: extract the logic from the event handler, move it to a different method, call that method from your current code and from the handler.

Comment: The `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method is called when a text field becomes the first responder. Why would you want that method called when you update the text of the text field?

Comment: @luk2303 thanks, yes that would work. But I would need to call it only from the textfield object. And I do not want to create a subclass of the textfield

Comment: @rmaddy thanks :) Although the "why would I need to call it" - thats a different issue. The thing is that, I need to call it :)

Comment: @PrakashRaman I do not fully understand that argument. And it is not a different issue. Those functions are event callbacks, you **should not**  and **should not have to** call them ;)

Comment: @PrakashRaman Then you are doing something fundamentally wrong. You should update your question with more details about the actual code you think you need.

Comment: Alright. Let me put it this way. I need a piece of code that will run when a textfield's value changes, either via user input or via textfield.text = <new text>

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I know it might be. But my question still stands :) My question is simple. Can I trigger a callback to be run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my answer and my reasoning:

I don't think it is possible to trigger those kind of events "by hand" - neither *should* you be able to. It would just cause possibly more problems than it solves. E.g. what should happen with the caret for example, should it be displayed in the textfield?

Therefore I suggest you extract the logic into a second method and call that method from your current code and from the handler

Instead of

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    // your logic is here
    let k = 1 + 2
}

func yourCurrentCode() {
    // somehow trigger the event "textFieldDidEndEditing"
}
```

do something like

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing() {
    myLogic()
}

func yourCurrentCode() {
    myLogic()
}

func myLogic() {
    // your logic should be here
    let k = 1 + 2
}
```

If you would like to be notified every time the value of the UITextField changes you should use the notification

```
UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
```

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. The thing is the "textfield" is passed to another object (of a different class) and that class does not have the "textFieldDidEndEditing". There I would like to call it on the context of the UITextField object.

Comment: @PrakashRaman I still do not fully understand. Can you give a detailed workflow example or code snippets that demonstrate what you are facing? Can't  you just get a hold of *that* object and call the desired method directly?

Comment: Thanks for the patience :) Let me try to expand better. I have a View (say vA) which has a textfield (tB), which also contains the mentioned callbacks. There exists another class (cC) which is initialized with tB. cC runs tB.text = (some text). At this point, I would need vA.textFieldDidEndEditing to be called. Although, I do not want to pass vA in the initializer. Hope this helps.

Comment: @PrakashRaman have you tried adding vA as Observer for the text property of tB? (you would have to google for how to that quickly) That way you would be notified when the text changes.

Comment: Let me look up observer. Currently, vA implements TextFieldDelegate only.

Comment: Ah, thanks ! Looks like "notification: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" would be the right way to solve my problem! Right ?

Comment: I went ahead and added your comment to your answer, so I could mark it as correct. Hope thats ok :) Thanks again !

Comment: @PrakashRaman probably the right one (since it seems to work ;) ) The edit is fine with me, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Brushing aside the situation you're trying to solve; regardless of wether this is the right approach; you can trigger UITextField events like this:

```
        textField.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```